# Scala no configuration key found

Tags: scala

I could extract value for

```
val ranking_score_path = cf.getString(stg + ".input.path.ranking_score")
  .replaceAll("_replace_date_", this_date)
```

and

```
val output_path = cf.getString(stg + ".output.path.hdfs") + tomz_date + "/"
```

but not

```
val AS_HOST = cf.getString(stg + ".output.path.aerospike.host")
println("AS_HOST = " + AS_HOST)
```

I have tried

1. replacing . with _,
2. adding commas

but didnt work.

error log

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'production.output.path.aerospike'
    at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
    at ...
```

application.conf

```
production {
  input {
    path {
      local = "/home/aduser/tmp/"
      hdfs = "/user/aduser/tmp_vincent/CPA/_replace_date_/intermediate/l1/"
      ranking_score = "/home/aduser/plt/item_performance/pipeline/cpa/output/_replace_date_/predict_output/ranking_score.csv"
    }
  }
  output {
    path {
      local = "/home/aduser/tmp/"
      hdfs = "/user/aduser/dyson/display/"
      aerospike {
        host = "0.0.0.0"
        port = 3000
        namespace = "test"
        set = "spark-test2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Reply @ Comment #1**

the cf is very long but the important part is as follows

```
... ore.csv"}},"output":{"path":{"hdfs":"/user/aduser/dyson/display/","local":"/home/aduser/tmp/"}}},"sun":{"arch": ...
```

**Effort #1: Replaced part of the application.conf**

```
    path {
          local = "/home/aduser/tmp/"
          hdfs = "/user/aduser/dyson/display/"
          ae_host = "0.0.0.0"
          ae_port = 3000
          ae_namespace = "test"
          ae_set = "spark-test2"
        }
```

and changed the calling method

```
val AS_HOST = cf.getString(stg + ".output.path.ae_host")
println("AS_HOST = " + AS_HOST)
```

but still getting errors

```
Exception in thread "main" com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'production.output.path.ae_host'
at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKeyOrNull(SimpleConfig.java:152)
```

Comment: Print/debug `cf` to check available keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem after several hours, my application.conf was at the same level with src.main.scala and it worked partially for reasons which I don't know. It worked perfectly after creating src.main.resources and putting application.conf inside.